# How to add custom icon to toolbar in stimulsoft tool

Tags: stimulsoft

How can I add custom icon to toolbar to allow user to change the height of header or footer using stimulsoft tool Asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to add custom icon on the toolbar in ASP.NET MVC components.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but How can I send data from Asp.net to stimulsoft designer?